# Not able to perform for loop in python as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the code:

```
var1 =[]
var5 =[]
var6 = []
var7 = []
var2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]
length = len(var2) - 1 # To use it for loop range
var3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
var4 = ['active','active','active','active','active','active']
for i in (0, length):
    with open("listsfile.txt") as f: 
        for line in f:
            if len(line.split(" ")) >= 4: # if strings more than or equal to 4 in line 
                var5 = line.split(" ") 
                var5 = filter(None, var5) # filter if any empty element
                if len(var5) >=3: # if list has more than or equal to 3 elements
                    cmp1 = str(var2[i])
                    cmp2 = str(var5[0])
                    print cmp1, cmp2
                    if cmp1 == cmp2: # if first string in a line is matched with list var2 then enter
                        print "xyz"
                        var6 = var5[0], var5[1], var5[2]
                        var7 = var2[i],var3[i],var4[i]
                        if var6 == var7:
                            print "Matched"
                        else:
                            print "Not Matched"
```

In above code i am not able to run 6 times in for loop "for i in (0, length):"

Actually I have to run var2 list length times(from 0 it should begin). But it is running only one time.

Please help.

Comment: You should use `for i in xrange(0, length):`, as `for i in (0, length):` means that you want to iterate a tuple with length 2, but `for i in xrange(0, length):` means that you want to iterate `length` times

Answer (score 0):

For python 3 "range" seems to do the trick. Also: var5 is now a filter, needs to be converted to list using list().

```
var1 =[]
var5 =[]
var6 = []
var7 = []
var2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]
length = len(var2) - 1 # To use it for loop range
var3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
var4 = ['active','active','active','active','active','active']
for i in range(0, length):
    with open("listsfile.txt") as f: 
        for line in f:
            if len(line.split(" ")) >= 4: # if strings more than or equal to 4 in line 
                var5 = line.split(" ") 
                var5 = list(filter(None, var5)) # filter if any empty element
                if len(var5) >=3: # if list has more than or equal to 3 elements
                    cmp1 = str(var2[i])
                    cmp2 = str(var5[0])
                    print (cmp1, cmp2)
                    if cmp1 == cmp2: # if first string in a line is matched with list var2 then enter
                        print ("xyz")
                        var6 = var5[0], var5[1], var5[2]
                        var7 = var2[i],var3[i],var4[i]
                        if var6 == var7:
                            print ("Matched")
                        else:
                            print ("Not Matched")
```